# WordPress Tiny MCE Create Split Button

Tags: php, tinymce, wordpress

I need help creating a split button in WordPress TinyMCE

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Wptuts', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('dropcap', {
                title : 'DropCap',
                cmd : 'dropcap',
                image : url + '/dropcap.jpg'
            });

            ed.addButton('showrecent', {
                title : 'Add recent posts shortcode',
                cmd : 'showrecent',
                image : url + '/recent.jpg'
            });

            ed.addCommand('dropcap', function() {
                var selected_text = ed.selection.getContent();
                var return_text = '';
                return_text = '<span class="dropcap">' + selected_text + '</span>';
                ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
            });

            ed.addCommand('showrecent', function() {
                var number = prompt("How many posts you want to show ? "),
                    shortcode;
                if (number !== null) {
                    number = parseInt(number);
                    if (number > 0 && number <= 20) {
                        shortcode = '[recent-post number="' + number + '"/]';
                        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("The number value is invalid. It should be from 0 to 20.");
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        // ... Hidden code
    });
    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wptuts', tinymce.plugins.Wptuts );
})();
```

I can create simple *buttons* for the `Wordpress TinyMCE Editor`
But I don't know how to create a split button. I'm really having trouble with this. I already searched on Google but I can't find a good examples for creating `split button`, can someone help me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ed.createSplitButton('splitbutton', {
   title : 'Splitbutton',
   image : url + '/splitbutton.jpg'
});
```